# Как сверстать пару блоков?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток! У меня возникли некоторые трудности при верстке одного макета, в котором есть пару скажем так "нестандартных" блоков, поэтому хотел спросить совета у более опытных разработчиков, писать код что да как не нужно, просто натолкните на мысль, каким бы способом Вы решили данную задачу, а я уже буду гуглить в данном направлении. В общем вот те пару блоков: 
[image: макет]

Как видно в первом блоке вообще пазл, его еще нужно будет как-то анимировать, но об этом позже, как можно сделать такой блок?
Во втором блоке куча всяких ненужных линий, которые запилил дизайнер и отговорить эго их убрать уже не возможно, поэтому нужен совет как их правильно сверстать. Насчет не ровного перехода с одного блока на другой я уже разобрался. Спасибо большое откликнувшимся!

Answer (score 0):

Решение для пазлов может быть таким http://sergeylukin.com/css-jigsaw-puzzle-piece/ 
А по скошенным блока вот хороший материал http://pcvector.net/scripts/layout_and_interface/242-skoshennye-elementy-na-css3.html

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ! Со скошенными блоками я уже разобрался, а пазл буду делать в последнюю очередь. Хотел спросить как верстать такие блоки? сетка там, абсолютным позиционированием? линии во втором блоке вообще не представляю как можно поместить, хотя саму линию сделать не проблема...

Comment: я бы использовала сетку хотя бы потому, что тут она в глаза бросается, колонки-строки. полоски можно навесить на псевдоэлементы блоков, то есть верстать его как трапецции css. ну это мое мнение, возможно вы найдете другое решение

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.